# Mathematica plotting has aliasing problem

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, missing-data

I'd like to show several pulses with different gaps.  I have the functions

```
g[y_] = Piecewise[{{-Sin[y], 0 < y < 2 Pi}, {0, y < 0}, {0, 
y > 2 Pi}}]
```

combined into

```
f[z_, t_] = g[z - t]
```

and

```
pulse[n_, t_, z_] = Sum[f[z, i t], {i, n}]
```

Sometimes it plots all pulses, and sometimes it does not.  Example when it works:
[Plot[{pulse[5, 40, z - 100]/4}, {z, 0, 1000},
PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, All}]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlHce.png)

Example when it fails:
[Plot[{pulse[5, 40, z - 200]/4}, {z, 0, 1000},
PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, All}]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e47yi.png)

And spectacular fail:
[Plot[{pulse[5, 30, z - 260]/4}, {z, 0, 1000},
PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, All}]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1W96.png)

Is there a way to fix this so that all pulses show up no matter what the parameters are?

Comment: Not on my computer.  The last example is still no plot.  But I will look more into that attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to see if we can get the same thing.

Go to

https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/LetMeMathematicaThatForYou.html

and patiently wait until the "Type your Wolfram..." appears.

One single left mouse click in the large empty white space below that.

Tap the x key and patiently wait until it appears.

Tap the backspace key and patiently wait until it disappears.

Scrape-n-paste exactly this

```
g[y_]:=Piecewise[{{-Sin[y],0<y<2Pi},{0,y<0},{0,y>2Pi}}];
f[z_,t_]:=g[z-t];
pulse[n_,t_,z_]:=Sum[f[z,i*t],{i,n}];
Plot[{pulse[5,30,z-260]/4},{z,0,1000},PlotRange->All]
```

into the large empty space and patiently wait until it appears.

Shift and Enter and patiently wait until the result appears.

I get no peaks.

Change that last line to be

```
Plot[{pulse[5,30,z-260]/4},{z,0,1000},PlotRange->All,PlotPoints->160]
```

and Shift and Enter and patiently wait until the result appears.

I get 5 peaks now.

If you do exactly this do you get exactly the same result?

You can change that 160 to 500 or even 1000 and seems to make very little difference in the displayed plot and only slows things down somewhat.

That web page is a very nice free service with tight restrictions on the size of input and amount of time before it aborts. Please do not abuse that. Thanks

Comment: I tried it on my computer - and that did work.  So it is the combination of both "All" and PlotPoints.  I had removed the PlotRange part when I tried just PlotPoints before.  Thanks!  I appreciate it!

Comment: I upped PlotPoints to 5000 and got it to work in a Manipulate quite well.  I basically get a solid block when the pulses are very close all the way to well spread out when appropriate.  I seem to have more trouble with delayed than without, so I need to work on understanding that better.  For now, I'm happy because the people who will be sliding the knobs can see things clearly.